# Python / Scrapy - output is cut off - hence wount let me correctly build queries with Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Im trying to scrape some data off a website using Scrapy and Python. The problem is the output of my search is always cut off. I tried this on 2 different Pcs. One is using windows 10, scrapy 1.4.0, python 2.7.13. The other is using Windows 7 ,scrapy 1.4.0, python 2.7.13. I have the same result on both computers.

Example :  (using scrapy shell on command line)

```
1. scrapy shell "www.reddit.com"
2. ..... some output comes here
3. response.xpath('//div')
```

4. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY8ch.png)

so the selectors got cut after a certain amount characters

another Example :
When using the Dev Tools on the website im trying to scrape(or any other site for that matter), i see the selector should be :

```
<Selector xpath='//div[@id="all_game_info"]' data=u'<div id="all_game_info" class="table_wrapper columns'>
```

When i access it with :

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="all_game_info"]')
```

then i get :

```
[<Selector xpath='//div[@id="all_game_info"]' data=u'<div id="all_game_info" class="table_wra'>]
```

so it cutt off a part. When i now try to search with the class variable like this

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="table_wra"]')
```

or

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="table_wrapper columns"]')
```

, then i get empty brackets []

Edit1: I am aware that i can scrape the data with .extract(). Im just wondering why its cut off, and why i cant access it with the @class variable

Comment: @BillBell here´s the new question! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want the selectors? If you check the page with the Dev Tools, you can check the tags and build your xpath from there. If you want the data, you'll need to add ".extract()".

Comment: the `data=` part of the `Selector` representation is kinda misleading: it is just a preview of the data. As @rongon mentions, use `.extract()` or `.extract_first()` (or the new `.get()` and `.getall()`) to get the "real" data out.

Comment: @paultrmbrth : i know i can extract it like that, but im asking myself why i can access it with one attribute (id) but not the other (class). Any suggestions?

Comment: Most certainly because the source HTML does not have `class="table_wrapper columns"` but something more, like `class="table_wrapper columns_wrapper"` or something. You can use `.extract_first()` to see what's in the HTML. or provide your source HTML in the question. `data=` is only the 40 first characters of the extracted data

Comment: Try
[contains(@class,"table_wrapper")]

Comment: @paultrmbrth site in question is : "http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201409040sea.htm" from the tutorial : "http://brutalsimplicity.github.io/2016/07/25/scrapy.html"

Comment: @Verz1Lka . i can find it like that, only problem i find alot more than i would like

Comment: @paultrmbrth can you explain that data=40char thing ? I think its exactly that whats causing my problem

Comment: `<Selector xpath='//div[@id="all_game_info"]' data=...'>` is simply a *representation* of a Selector. `data=` is only a *hint* at what you would extract. it is not the complete data.

Comment: @paultrmbrth aahhh... Thanks! But can you somehow extend that hint to show a bit more characters ? Or is there another function to show the full object ? Thanks  again!

Comment: You get the "full" object with `.extract()` on a `Selector`.

Comment: @paultrmbrth Can you expand on the "new `.get()`and `.getall()`? I couldn't find anything in the docs

Comment: They are in [parsel 1.2](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#id1). See [Selector objects](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#selector-objects) and [SelectorList objects](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#selectorlist-objects): they are aliases to always get a single value (or None) or a list of values (maybe empty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ scrapy shell 'http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201409040sea.htm'
2017-06-07 13:37:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: recordreviews)
(...)
>>> response.xpath('//div[@id="all_game_info"]')
[<Selector xpath='//div[@id="all_game_info"]' data='<div id="all_game_info" class="table_wra'>]
```

`<Selector xpath='//div[@id="all_game_info"]' data=u'<div id="all_game_info" class="table_wrapper columns'>` is only a representation of the `Selector` object.
The `data=` part only shows the 40 first characters of the data you *would* get with `.extract()` on that `Selector`.

See [the code here](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/blob/6ce4e11ad8f60e20a3b334b6a1c8a55d318ca569/parsel/selector.py#L335).

If you use `.extract_first()` (on the `SelectorList` you get from `response.xpath()`), you can see the raw HTML

```
>>> print(response.xpath('//div[@id="all_game_info"]').extract_first())
<div id="all_game_info" class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented columns">

<div class="section_heading">
  <span class="section_anchor" id="game_info_link" data-label="Game Info"></span>
    <h2>Game Info</h2>    <div class="section_heading_text">
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </div>      
</div>
<div class="placeholder"></div>
<!--
   <div class="table_outer_container">
      <div class="overthrow table_container" id="div_game_info">
  <table class="suppress_all sortable stats_table" id="game_info" data-cols-to-freeze=0><caption>Game Info Table</caption><tr class="thead onecell" ><td class="right center" data-stat="onecell" colspan="2" >Game Info</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="center " data-stat="info" >Won Toss</th><td class="center " data-stat="stat" >Seahawks (deferred)</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="center " data-stat="info" >Roof</th><td class="center " data-stat="stat" >outdoors</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="center " data-stat="info" >Surface</th><td class="center " data-stat="stat" >fieldturf </td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="center " data-stat="info" >Weather</th><td class="center " data-stat="stat" >71 degrees relative humidity 52%, wind 11 mph, wind chill 0</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="center " data-stat="info" >Vegas Line</th><td class="center " data-stat="stat" >Seattle Seahawks -8.5</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="center " data-stat="info" >Over/Under</th><td class="center " data-stat="stat" >45.0 <b>(over)</b></td></tr>

</table>

      </div>
   </div>
-->
</div>
>>>
```

The source HTML contains:

```
<div id="all_game_info" class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented columns">

<div class="section_heading">
  <span class="section_anchor" id="game_info_link" data-label="Game Info"></span>
    <h2>Game Info</h2>    <div class="section_heading_text">
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </div>      
</div>
...
```

The class value is `"table_wrapper setup_commented commented columns"`, not `"table_wrapper columns"`.

To match a node with XPath with `@class=`, you need an exact match:

```
>>> response.xpath('//div[@class="table_wrapper columns"]')
[]
>>> response.xpath('//div[@class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented columns"]')
[<Selector xpath='//div[@class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented columns"]' data='<div id="all_game_info" class="table_wra'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented columns"]' data='<div id="all_officials" class="table_wra'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented columns"]' data='<div id="all_home_starters" class="table'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented columns"]' data='<div id="all_vis_starters" class="table_'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented columns"]' data='<div id="all_home_snap_counts" class="ta'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented columns"]' data='<div id="all_vis_snap_counts" class="tab'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented columns"]' data='<div id="all_home_drives" class="table_w'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="table_wrapper setup_commented commented columns"]' data='<div id="all_vis_drives" class="table_wr'>]
>>>
```

If you want to match on *some* of the classes in the `class` attribute, you may want to have a look at CSS selectors:

```
>>> response.css('div.table_wrapper.columns')
[<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' table_wrapper ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' columns '))]" data='<div id="all_game_info" class="table_wra'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' table_wrapper ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' columns '))]" data='<div id="all_officials" class="table_wra'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' table_wrapper ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' columns '))]" data='<div id="all_home_starters" class="table'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' table_wrapper ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' columns '))]" data='<div id="all_vis_starters" class="table_'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' table_wrapper ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' columns '))]" data='<div id="all_home_snap_counts" class="ta'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' table_wrapper ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' columns '))]" data='<div id="all_vis_snap_counts" class="tab'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' table_wrapper ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' columns '))]" data='<div id="all_home_drives" class="table_w'>, <Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' table_wrapper ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' columns '))]" data='<div id="all_vis_drives" class="table_wr'>]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! 2 more questions from me : when i look at the html source it says : <div id="all_game_info" class="table_wrapper columns"> , nothing about the setup_commented commented , like in your example . 2 Question : why wount : response.xpath("//div[@class='table_wrapper columns']")    work ? best wishes

Comment: works when using "table_wrapper setup_commented commented columns". Thanks again! Any idea why Chrome seems to be cutting the class object when viewing with dev tools?